# How to fix function not running in VScode flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code, web

I am trying to make a website using flutter in VScode.
I wrote the code and ran Debug with chrome.

When a file is copied to a container by drag & drop, a function is implemented that shows the information of the file.

However, it cannot be copied as shown in the picture below.

I tried to see if there was a problem with the code or something else, but it didn't work.
There were no problems with the flutter doctor.

When I started Chrome with Android Studio,
it ran without any problem.

I'd like to know what's wrong with running debug in Chrome using VScode.

[image]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_dropzone/flutter_dropzone.dart';

class DropzoneWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropzoneWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropzoneWidget> createState() => _DropzoneWidgetState();
}

class _DropzoneWidgetState extends State<DropzoneWidget> {
  late DropzoneViewController controller;
  bool highlight = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final theme = Theme.of(context);
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 300,
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          DropzoneView(
            onCreated: (controller) => this.controller = controller,
            onDrop: acceptFile,
            onHover: () => setState(() => highlight = true),
            onLeave: () => setState(() => highlight = false),
            onError: (err) => print('run when error found : $err'),
          ),
          Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                const Icon(
                  Icons.cloud_upload,
                  size: 80,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Text(
                  'Drop Files here',
                  style: theme.textTheme.headline3,
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Future acceptFile(dynamic event) async {
    final name = event.name;
    final mime = await controller.getFileMIME(event);
    final bytes = await controller.getFileSize(event);
    final url = await controller.createFileUrl(event);
    print('Name: $name');
    print('mime: $mime');
    print('bytes: $bytes');
    print('url: $url');
  }
}
```

**.vscode/launch.json**

```
{
    
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "json_translator",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart"
        },
        {
            "name": "json_translator (profile mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "profile"
        },
        {
            "name": "json_translator (release mode)",
            "request": "launch",
            "type": "dart",
            "flutterMode": "release"
        },
        {
            "name": "Flutter (lib/main.dart)",
            "type": "dart",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "lib/main.dart",
            "args": [
                "-d",
                "chrome"
            ],

        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant parts of your code.

Comment: I added the code for that part. But in Android Studio, the code works fine.